# ROW_NUMBER() Performance optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

First, I would like to mention that I already checked all other asked questions, and none of it is similar to mine, so I don't think it's a duplicate.

I have two table tables, "Article_tbl" with more than 300,000 rows so far and "ArticleZone_tbl" with almost the same rows count.

"Article_tbl" Contains a Identity primary key, "ArticleID".
"ArticleZone_tbl" contains a primary key consisting of three columns, "ArticleID", "ChannelID", "ZoneID"; Where "ArticleID" is a foreign key from "Article_tbl"

Non clustered indexes were created on the columns to order by.

SQL Query:

```
WITH OrderedOrders AS(
Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by LastEditDate desc, ArticleOrder Asc, LastEditDateTime desc) as RowNum, dbo.Article_tbl.*, ArticleZone_tbl.ChannelID, ArticleZone_tbl.ZoneID, ArticleZone_tbl.ArticleOrder
From Article_tbl INNER JOIN ArticleZone_tbl
    ON dbo.Article_tbl.ArticleID = dbo.ArticleZone_tbl.ArticleID
Where ChannelID=1 And ZoneID=0)

SELECT * FROM OrderedOrders Where RowNum Between 1 And 10
```

The above query is taking about 2 seconds to complete, is there any way to optimize this query?

More info:
OS: Windows WebServer 2008R2
SQL Sever: 2008R2
RAM: 32GB
HDD: 160GB SSD

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
McHaimech

Comment: 2 seconds doesn't seem unreasonable for 300,000 rows.

Comment: Same query with "Over(Order by Article_tbl.ArticleID asc)" is taking 40ms, I should've mentioned this in my question.

Comment: When you say *"Non clustered indexes were created on the columns to order by."*, do you mean a single index on the 3 columns, or 3 indexes? Are the indexes sorted as they are in your query? Do you have indexes on `ChannelID` or `Zone`? Have you checked the execution plan to see what the most expensive operations are? Do your indexes have any non key columns?

Comment: What are the indexes exactly? My guess is a scan is being performed because the index doesn't match the OVER() clause. Can you show the plan? Does it recommend a different index?

Comment: A single non clustered index was created on "Article_tbl" for "LastEditDate", and "LastEditDateTime"
Another one was created on "ArticleZone_tbl" for "ArticleOrder"

Comment: Neither of those indexes support your query.

Comment: Execution Plan: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/7y81s4g7qil1fp6/Untitled.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try creating an [Indexed View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) on the two tables:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourIndexedView
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
    SELECT  az.ArticleID,
            az.ChannnelID,
            az.ZoneID,
            a.LastEditDate,
            a.LastEditDateTime,
            az.ArticleOrder
    FROM    dbo.Article_tbl a
            INNER JOIN dbo.ArticleZone_tbl az
                ON a.ArticleID = az.AtricleID;

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_YourIndexView_ArticleID_ChannelID_ZoneID 
    ON dbo.YourIndexedView (ArticleID, ChannelID, ZoneID);
```

Once you have your clustered index in place you can create a nonclustered index that would assist in the sorting:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourIndexedView_LastEditDate_ArticleOrder_LastEditDateTime
    ON dbo.YourIndexedView (LastEditDate DESC, ArticleOrder ASC, LastEditDateTime DESC);
```

You can then reference this in your query:

```
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(   SELECT  RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LastEditDate DESC, ArticleOrder ASC, LastEditDateTime DESC),
            ArticleID,
            ChannelID,
            ZoneID,
            LastEditDateTime,
            ArticleOrder
    FROM    dbo.YourIndexedView WITH (NOEXPAND)
    WHERE   ChannelID = 1 
    AND     ZoneID = 0
)
SELECT  *
FROM    OrderedOrders
WHERE   RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

*N.B. I may have missed some columns from your article table, but I couldn't infer them from the question*

Furthermore, if your query is always going to have the same zone and channel, you could filter the view, then your clustered index column simply becomes `ArticleID`:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourIndexedView
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
    SELECT  az.ArticleID,
            az.ChannnelID,
            az.ZoneID,
            a.LastEditDate,
            a.LastEditDateTime,
            az.ArticleOrder
    FROM    Article_tbl a
            INNER JOIN ArticleZone_tbl az
                ON a.ArticleID = az.AtricleID
    WHERE   az.ChannelID = 1
    AND     Az.ZoneID = 1;

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_YourIndexView_ArticleID 
    ON dbo.YourIndexedView (ArticleID);
```

Which means your indexes will be smaller, and faster to use.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Already had the view, but without the suggested indexes. Thanks a lot

Comment: For what it's worth, maintenance of tables which have schemabound indexed views is a major pain.  The view will drop schemabinding and the clustered index if the underlying table schema(s) are modified.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am aware of this. I am sure those two tables and the newly created query won't change any time soon, neither before some coming years.

Comment: @Ryan Can you elaborate please? I have not seen, nor am I able to replicate this behaviour. [In this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83a87b/1) the table schema is changed but with no effect on the view, and the index remains in the select query. [In this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83a87b/2) I cannot make a change to the schema that affects the view because it is bound to it. I know if you alter the view it will drop the indexes, but this is by design.

Comment: To be honest, it's somewhat dependent upon your SQL Management Studio settings.  There's an option ("Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation") where you can save changes to tables which require the table to be rebuilt (change of column data type, reordering of columns, etc).  In those destructive changes, schemabound views lose schemabinding and their index.

Comment: I had one case where a schemabound indexed view had full-text indexing enabled.  A change to underlying table schema dropped the schemabinding on the view, removed the index, and removed full-text indexing.  The lack of any full text-index on the view then broke application functionality (FreeText search)

Comment: Since the indexed view does not perform any aggregations, I wonder if it might be simpler (and more space economical, and less maintenance heavy) to put those supporting indexes on the base table instead.

Comment: @AaronBertrand How would you do this where the columns required are across 2 tables without the view? Even with the equivalent indexes on the base tables the expensive sort still exists: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2e23/1

Answer (score 1):

As you say "Same query with "Over(Order by Article_tbl.ArticleID asc)" is taking 40ms", no doubt that you have an index missing. You should study the query plan (include actual execution plan button in SSMS) 
One index with all fields covering your OVER(ORDER BY..) may give you good results.
ArticleId is implictly here because it is your cluster, respect the order ASC/DESC of your OVER clause.

try:

```
CREATE INDEX xxx on Article_tcl(LastEditDate desc, ArticleOrder asc, LastEditDateTime desc)
```

asc is the default you don't need to specify, here for clarity

Comment: It was a missing index, as I mentioned in my comment on the accepted post, I already had the view, but without the indexes

Answer (score 0):

I'd break the query up in to component parts.  Specifically, you don't need to bring back all column data in your subquery which determines row number and primary keys.  Additionally, breaking up the query will make it much easier to debug and optimize.

```
CREATE TABLE #OrderedRows( RowNumber int primary key, ArticleID int);
Create nonclustered index IX_OrderedRows_ByArticled on #OrderedRows (ArticleID);

insert into #OrderedRows
Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by LastEditDate desc, ArticleOrder Asc, LastEditDateTime desc) as RowNumber, Article_tbl.ArticleID
From Article_tbl 
INNER JOIN ArticleZone_tbl
    ON dbo.Article_tbl.ArticleID = dbo.ArticleZone_tbl.ArticleID
Where ChannelID=1 And ZoneID=0

SELECT oo.RowNumber, at.*, azt.ChannelID, azt.ZoneID, azt.ArticleOrder
FROM #OrderedOrders oo
join Article_tbl at
  on oo.ArticleID = at.ArticleID
INNER JOIN ArticleZone_tbl azt
    ON at.ArticleID = azt.ArticleID
    and azt.ChannelID = 1
    and azt.ZoneID = 0
Where oo.RowNumber Between 1 And 10

Drop table #OrderedRows;
```

Also, does adding the following indices affect performance?

```
create nonclustered index IX_Article_tbl_ByArticle_IncOrder on Article_tbl (ArticleID) Include (ArticleOrder);
create nonclustered index IX_ArticleZone_tbl_Cover on ArticleZone_tbl (ChannelID, ZoneID, ArticleID, ArticleDate, ArticleTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but got almost the same delay plus another 150ms

Comment: Mind posting a plan for using this method?