# Query Performance is down because of Row_Number()

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Account, a.Product, a.[Week] ORDER BY  a.WaterFallMeasures) AS [Row], 
    col1, col2
FROM
    View
```

I have millions of records in the table. Query performance is down because of `row_number()`. How to optimize it?

Comment: indexes. indexes. indexes

Comment: Make sure you have proper indexes to assist with the sort etc. You could also create indexed views, see [ROW_NUMBER performance optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230172/row-number-performance-optimization)

Comment: "Indexing won't be much help unless that view is an indexed view.."  - that's incorrect. Unless it's nested views which as we know often get the optimiser  confused.

Answer (score 0):

First... Consider loosing the view and reference the base tables directly. Views, particularly complex views and/or nested views, have a nasty habit of fooling the optimizer, leading to sub-optimal query plans. (note: the above does not apply to indexed views)

Second, you'll want what's called a [POC index (Partitioning, Ordering, and Coverage)](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/sql-server-2012-how-write-t-sql-window-functions-part-3). So, in your case it would be...

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_BaseTable_Account_Product_Week_WaterFallMeasures ON dbo.BaseTable 
    (Account, Product, Week, WaterFallMeasures) INCLUDE (col1, col2);
```